# Get latest item activity as one line per item

Tags: sql, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Experts,
I have a query that shows me the latest Item activity for both the Order and Invoice tables. I need to narrow this down even more, by only showing One result per Item - the newest activity whether that was the Order or Invoice...

```
SELECT A.ItemCode, A.ObjType, A.DocNum, A.LastActivity

FROM
(SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T1.[ObjType], T1.[DocNum], T1.[DocDate] AS 'LastActivity',
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T0.ItemCode ORDER BY T0.DocEntry DESC) AS 'rownum'
 FROM INV1 T0
      INNER JOIN OINV T1 ON T0.[DocEntry]=T1.[DocEntry]
    WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001_ test non inventory' OR T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001'

 UNION ALL

 SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T1.[ObjType], T1.[DocNum], T1.[DocDate] AS 'LastActivity',
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T0.ItemCode ORDER BY T0.DocEntry DESC) AS 'rownum'
 FROM RDR1 T0
    INNER JOIN ORDR T1 ON T0.[DocEntry]=T1.[DocEntry]

    WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001_ test non inventory' OR T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001'
    ) A
WHERE A.rownum=1;
```

Comment: Did `Top 1 ... `not work?

Comment: When adding Top 1 at the first SELECT it brings back only one item record. When I added it to the 2 embedded SELECTS it brought back the same Item for both SO and Invoice.

Comment: If you could add some sample data or what output you are getting with this query it might make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `row_number` to the outer query and wrap the entire thing in another query:

```
SELECT A.ItemCode, A.ObjType, A.DocNum, A.LastActivity
FROM
(
    SELECT A.ItemCode, A.ObjType, A.DocNum, A.LastActivity,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode ORDER BY DocEntry DESC) AS 'rownum'

    FROM
    (
        SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T1.[ObjType], T1.[DocNum], T0.[DocEntry], T1.[DocDate] AS 'LastActivity'
        FROM INV1 T0
        INNER JOIN OINV T1 
            ON T0.[DocEntry]=T1.[DocEntry]
        WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001_ test non inventory' 
        OR T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T1.[ObjType], T1.[DocNum], T0.[DocEntry], T1.[DocDate] AS 'LastActivity'
        FROM RDR1 T0
        INNER JOIN ORDR T1 
            ON T0.[DocEntry]=T1.[DocEntry]
        WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001_ test non inventory' 
        OR T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001'
    ) A
) B
WHERE A.rownum=1;
```

Tip: You can make queries more readable by replacing derived tables with common table expressions:

```
WITH CTEUnion AS
(
        SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T1.[ObjType], T1.[DocNum], T0.[DocEntry], T1.[DocDate] AS 'LastActivity'
        FROM INV1 T0
        INNER JOIN OINV T1 
            ON T0.[DocEntry]=T1.[DocEntry]
        WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001_ test non inventory' 
        OR T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T1.[ObjType], T1.[DocNum], T0.[DocEntry], T1.[DocDate] AS 'LastActivity'
        FROM RDR1 T0
        INNER JOIN ORDR T1 
            ON T0.[DocEntry]=T1.[DocEntry]
        WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001_ test non inventory' 
        OR T0.[ItemCode] = 'A00001'        
), CTERowNum AS
(
    SELECT ItemCode, ObjType, DocNum, LastActivity,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode ORDER BY DocEntry DESC) AS 'rownum'
    FROM CTEUnion
)

SELECT ItemCode, ObjType, DocNum, LastActivity
FROM CTERowNum
WHERE rownum=1;
```